# PHP/HTML on Safari from Mac Os 10.6.5 works very slowly

Tags: php, html, macos, google-chrome, safari

This is the script:

```
<?php

require_once 'swift-mailer/lib/swift_required.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$form_subject = $_POST['form_subject'];
$form_message = $_POST['form_message'];

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if ($_POST['name'] != "") {
            $_POST['name'] = filter_var($_POST['name'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            if ($_POST['name'] == "") {
                $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {
            $errors .= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
        }

        if ($_POST['email'] != "") {
            $email = filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
            if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                $errors .= "$email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/><br/>";
            }
        } else {
            $errors .= 'Please enter your email address.<br/>';
        }

        if ($_POST['form_subject'] != "") {
            $form_subject = filter_var($_POST['form_subject'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            if ($_POST['form_subject'] == "") {
                $errors .= 'Please enter a valid subject.<br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {
            $errors .= 'Please enter your subject.<br/>';
        }

        if ($_POST['form_message'] != "") {
            $form_message = filter_var($_POST['form_message'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
            if ($_POST['form_message'] == "") {
                $errors .= 'Please enter a valid comment.<br/><br/>';
            }
        } else {
            $errors .= 'Please enter your comment.<br/>';
        }


if (!$errors) {


//File upload

// Where the file is going to be placed 
$target_path = "uploads/";

// Add the original filename to our target path.  
//Result is "uploads/filename.extension" 
$target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'])) {

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}   
}
//End of file upload

//Create the Transport
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

//Create the Mailer using your created Transport
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

//Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();

  //Give the message a subject
$message->setSubject('New data submitted');

$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date=date("l, F j, Y, g:i a");

  //Give it a body
$message->setBody("Here is the information submitted to 
www.polycysticliverdisease.com/html/contact_email.php 
from $ip on $date.\n\n
--------------------------------\n\n
name: $name \n\n
email address: $email \n\n
subject: $form_subject \n\n
comment: $form_message");

  //Add alternative parts with addPart()
//$message->addPart('My amazing body in plain text', 'text/plain');

//Create the attachment
// * Note that you can technically leave the content-type parameter out
$attachment = Swift_Attachment::fromPath($target_path);  

//Attach it to the message
$message->attach($attachment);

//Using setTo() to set all recipients in one go
$message->setTo(array('INFO@POLYCYSTICLIVERDISEASE.COM' => 'Diane Smith'));

//Set a From: address including a name
$message->setFrom(array('INFO@POLYCYSTICLIVERDISEASE.COM' => 'Contact Us'));

//Send the message
$numSent = $mailer->send($message);

//printf("Sent %d messages\n", $numSent);

if(isset($_FILES['uploadedfile'])){
$pathfile = "/home/vitusya/eximi.dreamhosters.com/Hawaii/html/uploads/" . $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
@unlink($pathfile);
}

$to = "$email";
$subject = "Thank You!";
$body = "Thank you for e-mailing us.  We will reply as soon as possible.";
mail($to, $subject, $body);

        }


        else {
            echo '<div style="color: red">' . $errors . '<br/>
                </div>';



        }
    }



?>
```

This is the form:

```
    <form name="contact" action="contact_email.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h2 class="lower">Contact Us</h2>
                </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="pretty_border">
                    <label for="name">Your Name:</label><br />
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="name" />
                    <br />
                </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="pretty_border">
                    <label for="email">Your E-Mail Address:</label><br />
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="email" />
                    <br />
                </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="pretty_border">
                    <label for="form_subject">Subject:</label><br />
                    <input class="text" type="text" name="form_subject" />
                    <br />
                </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td class="textarea_border">
                    <label for="form_message">Your Message:</label><br />
                    <textarea rows="7" cols="50" name="form_message"></textarea>
                    <br />
                </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>    
                <td>
                    <div class="fileinputs">
                        <input type="submit" class="file" name="submit" />
                        <div class="fakefile">
                                <img src="../assets/images/submit_btt.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fileinputs">
                        <input type="file" class="file" name="uploadedfile" />
                        <div class="fakefile">
                                <img src="../assets/images/uf_btt.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fileinputs">
                        <input type="reset" class="file" />
                        <div class="fakefile">
                                <img src="../assets/images/reset_btt.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fileinputs">
                        <input type="button" class="file" onclick="window.print()" />
                        <div class="fakefile">
                                <img src="../assets/images/print_btt.png" />
                        </div>                      
                    </div>
                </td>   
            </tr>

        </table>
        </form>
```

All works fine on Windows with any browser, also it works fine on iPhone and iPad.
It seems that the problem is in Mac.
The script executes really slowly and sends the 'thank you' letter to a user from a wrong email address.
Also it seems that Google Chrome on Mac has the same problem.

What do you think it could be?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean this script run on your Mac executes slowly or that the page does not work from Safari on Mac 10.6.5?

Comment: Is the server running on your local mac for development purposes? If it is, that will add to the list of possible bottlenecks. If it's not, the solution will be that little bit easier to find :-)

Comment: Just use xdebug and profile your script. (Else my guess is that the slowness comes from your use of XHTML syntax but absence of XHTML mime type.)

Comment: Well, it runs slowly on any Safari on Mac 10.6.5, I guess.
I don't think it

Comment: My client went to an Apple store and tested it on several computers there.

Comment: She also says that it works the same way with Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

the execution time has nothing to do with the browser php is a serverside language
you should debug your code by echo out the various variable you have through out the script and check if they have the value they're suppose to, if not you might look into the code previous to where you echo'd out the variable to find what might have gone wrong